# How to assign the same style to all textFields in Xcode 5 iOS7?

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I am new in programming with Xcode and objective C. 
I am currently building an app that has a lot of elements like text fields, labels and buttons. 
I just want to know if I am able to build a resource file with custom style for each of this elements and assign it to them. 
It would be really a hard and difficult job if I have to change the style of this elements manually one by one if changes are required.

Any idea?

Comment: What sort of customization do you want to do to your UITextField? Subclassing is a good option, but it might be overkill if you just want a little bit. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods of `UITextField` are your friend:

```
[[UITextField appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica"
                                                      size:14.0]];
[[UITextField appearance] setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
```

There are many more.

This means that any UITextField you make will have this font and style to begin with.

Comment: @user3107262 You want this to be in effect everywhere in your code, so you should put this in your AppDelegate.m file, in the `applicationDidFinish` method (the first one). For future reference, this is a good place to put anything you want to do before anything else happens.

Comment: What if I want to assign two different styles for my text fields .. . what do I have to do?

Comment: @user3107262 In that case, you should ask a separate question, but it should be as simple as this: `textFieldThatLooksDifferent.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:36.0f];
    textFieldThatLooksDifferent.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;` If you want to have two styles that you reuse frequently, you should subclass `UITextField`. If you ever want to see what properties you can change on a variable, it's a good idea to just go `variable.` and see what pops up on XCode. Like try `variable.font` and you realize, "Oh, I can just change the font!"